# Import CSV to Heroku database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csv, heroku

In a Rails application that is deployed to Heroku I need to import a CSV.

How Can I fill the tables in Heroku with that csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about doing this programatically, a combination of FasterCSV (built into 1.9) and ActiveRecord are your best bet.

http://blog.pioneeringsoftware.co.uk/2010/07/13/import-csv-files-in-rails-3

If you're looking to push the CSV directly into Postgres then you need to make the file available for PG to see and then open the file from there.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: I've been trying the second option. Does anyone know how to give the database permission to open a file on Heroku?? I'm using nodejs, but sure the answer is analogous.

Answer (score 1):

Importing a CSV dump of Postgres data into Heroku:

https://gist.github.com/jboesch/5605747